# Help identifying this set, dark red and dark grey airplane body?

Tags: set-identification

Bought in a random box with mostly Star Wars, Indiana Jones, and Ninjago sets, and a few one offs. Before I have to enter every piece into rebrickable, I was hoping someone might be able to identify this?

[image: img]

Comment: Welcome to Brick Answers.  Are you looking for the set for this to be found or the individual part numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is from [9467-1: The Ghost Train](https://brickset.com/sets/9467-1/The-Ghost-Train)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear! The set. Thank you Joost!